# itext chunk background color for rtf

Tags: java, itext, rtf

I used itext to create an rtf file. I want add a background color to the text with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    Document document = new Document();
    try {

        RtfWriter2 rtf = RtfWriter2.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("text.rtf"));
        document.open();

        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("This is a text");
        chunk.setBackground(new Color(0xFF,0x00,0x00),0f,0f,0f,0f);


        Phrase fa = new Phrase();
        fa.add(chunk);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add(fa);



        document.add(p);
        document.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

When I open it in Mac, I cannot see the background color shown. But when I try to use Word to open it, the background color is shown. Thus,

Is it the right way to highlight a text block in rtf?
When I use JEditorPane to open it, the background color still cannot show.